# Magento 2.3.X Country of Origin or Manufacture attribute doesn't save on product page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3, product-page

I'm trying to save 'country of manufacture' attribute on product page but it's not save it. Other attributes is save successful. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Can you give more information? error on screen or system/exception logs

Comment: I'm not getting error. it says saved but it does not save.

Comment: check your servers max_post_size if there are a lot of options also check your server memory_limit. if you are unsure how to do this then i would advise you speak to your hosting company